# Unable to see Test Plan results

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

I am unable to see Test Plan results for a test plan in Microsoft Test Manager.
Following error is displayed.

[image] 
Plan contains automated unit tests which are data driven from Test case in MTM. I am putting some value to a field in MTM and passing it during the execution on basis of Test Case ID.

I am not sure why i am not able to see the test results in **Plan** tab.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to diagnose the problem is to activate *MTM* logging.

Please check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223879/microsoft-test-manager-cannot-install-test-agent-on-these-machines-when-creati/19248161#19248161): there I described how to do it.